# PHP form sending blank mails

Tags: php, forms, email

I've been searching on SO for a while now and I can't seem to find the answer to my problem. I have a PHP mail script that successfully send emails to the right mail address, no problem there. I'm using Gmail as my mail client and it's working good, but when I checked the webmail at my hosts site (Mamutmail at active24) I notice that a lot of emails won't be redirected to Gmail.

When I started using my mail script a year ago I also received a lot of blank mails, even though I have a working validation on the form. I get like 5-8 blank mails per day, but I decided to filter them away in Gmail after I've been googling a lot and considered it to be a "random hosts issue" (I know, it's stupid).

So, to summarize:

--> mails sent from the form on the website are being sent to the hosts webmail but some are not imported to my Gmail

--> I get many blank mails every day even thought I have a validation

This is my form code:

```
<form id="mailForm" method="post" action="sendMailPre.php">
            Ditt namn <span style="color: red;">*</span><br/>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="required" /><br/><br/>

            Din mailadress <span style="color: red;">*</span><br/>
            <input type="text" name="mail" class="required email" /><br/><br/>

            Ditt telefonnummer<br/>
            <input type="text" name="tele" /><br/><br/>

            Din stad<br/>
            <input type="text" name="city" /><br/><br/>

            Ditt meddelande <span style="color: red;">*</span><br/>
            <textarea type="text" name="message" rows="8" class="required"></textarea><br/><br/>

            <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Skicka meddelande" /><br/><br/>
            </form>
```

And this is the mail script in PHP:

```
$ToEmail = 'test@mail.com'; 
$EmailSubject = $_POST["name"] . ' - Mail från hemsidan';
$mailheader = 'From: ' . $_POST["name"] . '' . "\n" .
'Reply-To: ' . $_POST["mail"] . '' . "\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()."\n";


$mailheader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$mailheader .= "Content-Type: text/html; UTF-8\n";

$message = '<html><head>';
$message .= '<style>';
$message .= 'body{line-height: 60%; padding: 35px; margin: 0;}';
$message .= '</style></head>';
$message .= '<body>';
$message .= '<span style="font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: #4c7eb0; font-weight: normal;">NAMN</span><br/>';
$message .= str_replace("\n", "<br />", ($_POST["name"])); 
$message .= '<br/><br/>';
$message .= '<span style="font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: #4c7eb0; font-weight: normal;">MAIL</span><br/>';
$message .= str_replace("\n", "<br />", ($_POST["mail"])); 
$message .= '<br/><br/>';
$message .= '<span style="font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: #4c7eb0; font-weight: normal;">TELEFONNUMMER</span><br/>';
$message .= str_replace("\n", "<br />", ($_POST["tele"])); 
$message .= '<br/><br/>';       $message .= '<span style="font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: #4c7eb0; font-weight: normal;">STAD</span><br/>';   $message .= str_replace("\n", "<br />", ($_POST["city"]));  $message .= '<br/><br/>';
$message .= '<span style="font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: #4c7eb0; font-weight: normal;">MEDDELANDE</span><br/>';
$message .= str_replace("\n", "<br />", ($_POST["message"])); 
$message .= '</span>';
$message .= '</body></html>';
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $message, $mailheader) or die ("Meddelandet kunde inte skickas.");
```

Would really appreciate some help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Working validation "where"? Javascript? in PHP? If it's javascript, that's trivially easy to bypass.

Comment: @MarcB It's in Javascript. Is it easy to bypass? Can you recommend any good validation?

Answer (score 2):

I would be willing to bet that your script is set up in such a way as any time anyone loads that page it fires off an email.  I would include a hidden variable:

```
<input type="hidden" name="formEmail" value="1"/>
```

Then check for it in $_POST["formEmail"] on the sendMailPre.php page, and only send an email if that variable is there.

My best guess is you're probably getting search engine bots hitting the page.

Comment: or just wrap the whole generate/send logic in `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { ... }`. checking for particular form fields can be unreliable.

Comment: @MarcB So far so good with your solution, gonna wait an hour or two before I can see if it truly works or not. But thanks to both of you for the fast responses!